# Calling one module method into throwing undefined error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-2016

I have a project structure looks like this.

> > src/core/sample1.js

```js
class MyPro1 { 
  constructor() { 
  }

  print_data() { 
    return 'Prine';
  }

  smaple_data() { 
    console.log(this.print_data());
    return 'this';
  }
}

module.exports = MyPro1;
```

> > src/externals/polis.js

```js
const MyPro1 = require('../core/sample1');
const MyPro = require('../utils/usable');

class MyRock { 
  constructor() { 
    this.content = new MyPro1();
  }

  call_methods() { 
    let data = MyPro.smaple_data('100', this.content.smaple_data, null);
    console.log(data);
  }
}

const x = new MyRock();
x.call_methods();
```

> > src/utis/usable.js

```js
class MyPro {

  static smaple_data(data, method, call) {
    method();
    return data;
  }
}

module.exports = MyPro;
```

I am calling utils and core js files inside it. It throws error but don't know how to solve this error.

```
Traceback
console.log(this.print_data());

TypeError: Cannot read property 'print_data' of undefined
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the context is lost with `this.content.smaple_data`, you probably need `()  -> this.content.smaple_data()` instead (or arrow functions).

Comment: @sp00m Can you please elobrate I'm new to this.

Comment: sp00m is correct. Btw, `MyPro` probably should be a simple object literal not a `class`.

Comment: @utks009 It's all very well explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/1225328 already :)